# To create Swipeable tabs without ActionBar

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, swipe-gesture

I would like to create swipeable tabs without action bar at its top as shown as in the [link](http://prntscr.com/941lmr). I've used the following lines : setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); 
 setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

Also here is my Layout [xml](http://prntscr.com/941muc).

Can anyone please help me how I can achieve this.

Comment: Show your layout.xml please

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau, I've added my xml layout for your reference

Answer (score 0):

Your layout should be set up similar to this:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ToolBar/>
    <TabBar/>
    <ViewPager/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also you should choose a theme without ActionBar (i.E. `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`) for your application, and not call `setSupportActionbar()`